# Handling geolocation with meteor framework

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I handle geolocation success and failure events within the meteor framework?
More specifically, the call "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);" says to call showPosition if there was success in getting the location. Whenever I define a generic javascript function (function showPosition(position) {}) I get a web socket error. So how do I call these functions within the meteor framework?

Answer (score 1):

Check the module [mdg:geolocation](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/)

```
meteor add mdg:geolocation
```

After use it in your code:

```
Geolocation.currentLocation()
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a meteor feature specifically. It works with geolocation compatible browsers. Once you get the location you can send it or save it via Meteor.

Client side js: (make sure the collection exists on the server)

```
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
   else{
       console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    Locations.insert({latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
                      longitude: position.coords.longitude});
}
```

Comment: For some reason creating generic JavaScript functions within the client side js file it caused the socket to close. I used delegates to solve this but not sure if that's the correct way.

Comment: which socket closes? The meteor sockjs one should reconnect if it ever disconnects. Could you post your code sample up? This really shouldn't happen at all.